# Python script made into an executable: how to prune the output

Tags: python, executable

I made an executable out of a python script as suggested here:

https://superuser.com/questions/1164706/how-do-i-make-a-python-file-executable-on-macos-sierra

so modifying the extension into `.command` and making it executable.

When I double-click on it, it works fine as I expect, but it also prints out a lot of stuff I'm not interested in (see screenshot). How can I make it NOT print the lines different from "Hello World!"?

[Output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Ech.png)

In case the image was not visible, I paste the output here:

```
Last login: Wed Jun  3 19:15:14 on xxx
(base) xxx-di-xxx:~ xxx$ /Users/xxx/Desktop/Core/Programmi_miei/TestExecutable/HelloWorld.command ; exit;
Hello world!
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

I'm using Mac 10.13.6.